async function's body is being executed earlier than another async function finishes executing
I'm making weather forecasting app using JavaScript fetch api. I want to recieve data from processFormat function and use that data in showResults function, but can't, because for some reason showResults function is being executed earlier than processFormat function
const processFormat = async (range) => {
    let getCityUrl = `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${city}&limit=${limit}&appid=${apiKey}`;
    //resultStates.length = 0; 
    fetch(getCityUrl)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        data.forEach((item) => {
            console.log(item);
            resultStates.push(item.state);
            resultObj[item.state] = {
                'lat': item['lat'],
                'lon': item['lon']
            };
        });
    })
    .catch(rejected => {
        console.log(rejected);
    })
    console.log(resultObj);
};
//...
const showResults = async (range) => {
    await processFormat(range);
    for (let i=0; i<Object.keys(resultObj).length; i++) {
        resultStates.push(Object.keys(resultObj)[i]);
    }
    console.log(`resultStates: ${resultStates}`)
    if (resultStates.length === 0) {
        resultSection.textContent = `Failed to find your city: ${city}. Try another city`;
        setTimeout(() => {
            resultSection.textContent = '';
            clickedSearch = 0;
        }, 5000);
    }
    else {
        //...
    }
};

I tried putting await processFormat(range); in the first line of processFormat function, it didn't help. I see that the object and the array in output are empty. Why?

console.log(resultObj) is executed synchronously, it doesn't wait for the fetch() callbacks to execute.

If you put that in showResults after await processFormat(range) you should see the desired results.

Why are you using the global variable? You should have processFormat() return the results, then you can use const resultObj = await processFormat(range);

What's the reason for both functions having to mutate the two outer scope references resultStates and resultObj?

Actually, the real problem is that processFormat() doesn't use await fetch(...). So it returns before fetch() has completed.

@Barmar that's it! thank you so much, I have really missed "await fetch()"

Always be wary if a function is declared async but doesn't use await -- I wonder if any IDEs warn about this.

@Liza ... Regarding the so far provided sole answer, are there any questions left?

Besides the already mentioned obvious cause of defect ...
... the OP is encouraged to drop the mutation of outer scope references where they are not really needed. Each function should be responsible for working upon data/state which either has been created within the function itself or acquired as a result of another function call. Thus, with cutting off this kind of dependencies, a function is better testable and maintainable. In addition the OP also might consider switching entirely to the async-await syntax. It might be easier to read/comprehend than a promise's chained then-catch methods.
A refactored version of the OP's example code then might look similar to the following provided variant ...
async function processFormat({ city, limit, apiKey }) {
  let response, data, error = null;
  try {

    response = await fetch(
      `http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=${city}&limit=${limit}&appid=${apiKey}`;
    );
    data = await response.json();

  } catch(exception) {

    error = exception;
  }
  return [
    error,
    (error !== null) && data

      .reduce(({ stateNames, stateLookup }, { state, lat, lon }) => {

        stateNames.push(state);
        stateLookup[state] = { lat, lon };

        return { stateNames, stateLookup };

      }, { stateNames: [], stateLookup: {} }) || data,
  ];
}

async function showResults({ city, limit, apiKey }) {
  const [
    error, result,
  ] =
    await processFormat({ city, limit, apiKey });

  if (error === null) {

    console.log(`'processFormat' failed with error ... ${ error }.`);

  } else if (result.stateNames.length === 0) {

    console.log(`Failed to find your city: ${ city }.`);
  } else {
    console.log({ stateLookup: result.stateLookup });
  }
}

